# How to stop tnt exploding automatically when summoned?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am having an issue where when I do the command `/summon tnt ~ ~ ~`, `/summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:80}`, `/summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {FuseTime:80}`, or any other fuse it automatically explodes the tnt. I've seen other questions on here with the same premise but haven't found any answer that works for me. I've tried changing the fuse, setting the fuse to 100 or 50 etc. on multiple worlds but I'm not making any progress. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions, I'm grateful for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using `/setblock` instead of `/summon`?

Comment: I hadn't, but that won't work in my case because I want the tnt to be lit upon summoning , and lit tnt is an entity, not a block.

Comment: You tagged Minecraft Java, is that really your version? Because NBT tags don't work on Bedrock

Comment: Yes, I am on minecraft's Java Edition. I am on 1.20.4.

Comment: [Related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405916/what-is-the-command-to-summon-an-ignited-tnt-block-as-of-1-20-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
/summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:80}
```

The `f` should be lowercase. That's the only error in your command. If this doesn't solve the problem there could be another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a server by chance?
If so check the following

1. You have operator permissions.
2. The server is not using the plugin "Essential" or any of its sister plugins.

If operator permissions are missing, commands will not run.
If the server is using Essential(s) or related plugins, type:

> /minecraft:summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:80}

A small difference to you, but it tells Minecraft to run the command located in Minecraft namespace (plugins just change the default namespace).